# Crystal Report Displaying only one row in each page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, datatable

I am using Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2012. I am totally new to crystal reports. I just added my data fields to the details section, but instead of showing all the rows in one page, a new page is created for each row. I did not use any grouping or change the section paging settings.

Even i checked the section expert for new page after & before, its uncheked.
I also checked Keep Together, its checked.

I have added the data in details section and i have only one details section.

I have attached a screen shot my crystal report design view

Guys please help me... I am stuck with this

![Report Preview][1]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/reportay.jpg/

![Report Design Mode][2]
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/reportdesign.jpg/

Thank You In advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reduce the whitespace in the details area [at  Design Mode].
**Every row gets the height of the details area, so that area should only be one row high.**
[image: Crystal reports design view with emphasis on details section row height.]

*Edit:* Make the report footer the same as the details section, but without any data fields. This way the report will be filled from end of data to beginning of page footer if (when) the datarows does not fill up the last page.

Comment: I have almost reduced the whitespace area in design view its still the same....And also checked the row height of individual record and modified as per my requirement. I have also exported the report in pdf checked. Each record is displayed in individual page....

Comment: You still have HUGE amount of vertical white space in your report as in the last of your comments. I'll upload a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply..I have removed the white-space and my design looks like this http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7818/reportdesign.jpg
http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/9011/reportpreview.jpg

Comment: have tried which LapplandsCohan said in the above answer? The detail section should be small as shown in the above pic. try to reduce the box height in detail section and get back with ur results.

Comment: Thank You guys One and all Hariharan, LapplandsCohan. Now i understand how crystal report works. I am a Software Engineer working on .Net relating to CAD/CAM industry. I have never used Crystal Report till now this was my first time. You guys were right i have to decrease the row height to only one row.  Thank You once again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using Details Section to display all those rows. Because if u happen to use page header or report header, the rows wont grow.

If you are sure that you have reduced the white space in design view, then check with the "New Page Before" or "New Page After" options in Section Expert.

Please try all these and get back with the results you get. Waiting to help you !

Comment: I have uploaded the image of the Report Design, Preview(page 1 & 10) & Section Expert. The links are http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/482/reportsectionexpert.jpg
http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/3199/previewpg1.jpg
http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/6397/previewpg10.jpg
http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/3487/reportdesigner.jpg

Comment: I have done as per your suggestion. Please check the images, i know there is some minor mistake which i am unable to figure out.

Comment: in this image http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/3487/reportdesigner.jpg Section 3 (Detail) is too big, try to reduce the height of that section. So your probl can be solved

Comment: http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7818/reportdesign.jpg Check this link i have changed the height, even then it the result is same. The preview of my report is here http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/9011/reportpreview.jpg

Comment: Thank You guys One and all Hariharan, LapplandsCohan. Now i understand how crystal report works. I am a Software Engineer working on .Net relating to CAD/CAM industry. I have never used Crystal Report till now this was my first time. You guys were right i have to decrease the row height to only one row. Thank You once again.

Comment: Happy that your problem got resolved !
Even im a .Net Developer. Ready help you in future too !!